# AngularJS Databinding - Inputs not updating from model

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I've been doing a lot of googling and I can't figure out why this won't work. I have a "PlayerController" and a form to add a new player. The inputs are bound to $scope.NewPlayer.name and $scope.NewPlayer.color and updates the scope variables when changed. When you click "add new player" the form should reset the scope variables so the inputs are empty.

```
$scope.startNew = function()
{
    $scope.NewPlayer.name = "";
    $scope.NewPlayer.color = "";

    $("#new_player_modal").modal("show");
}
```

But this doesn't update. Tried $scope.$apply() and $scope.$digest() and it says

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
```

Here is the HTML

```
    <!-- Player Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="new_player_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" ng-controller="PlayerController">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create a New Player</h4>
          </div>
          <form id="new_player_form" ng-submit="startNewSubmit()">
          <div class="modal-body">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="NewPlayer.name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Leave Blank To Enter Later">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Color</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="NewPlayer.color" class="form-control color-input" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="HEX Color">
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </form>
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: to clear up confusion-

```
$scope.startNewSubmit = function()
{
    var cont = true;
    if($scope.newPlayerColor)
    {
        Player = $scope.getPlayerByColor($scope.newPlayerColor);
        if(Player != null)
        {
            alert("Player Color Already Selected!");
            cont = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please choose a color.");
        cont = false;
    }

    if($scope.newPlayerName)
    {
        Player = $scope.getPlayerByName($scope.newPlayerName);
        if(Player != null)
        {
            alert("Player Name Already In Use!");
            cont = false;
        }
    }

    if(cont)
    {
        var Player = {"name":$scope.newPlayerName,"color":$scope.newPlayerColor};
        $scope.players.push(Player);

        $("#new_player_modal").modal("hide");
    }
}
```

startNew and startNewSubmit are different.

Comment: Your method in controller called ```startNew```, and in view you call ```startNewSubmit```

Comment: Where is your main html with the button "Create New Player" with startNew method from which you show the modal window? Also why don't you use $modal service and use jquery like approach?

Comment: startNew and startNewSubmit are different.

I don't know anything about the angularjs modal. I'm new to this.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/23t4b/1/

To answer your question: you are using your models as `NewPlayer.name` and `NewPlayer.color`, while you are referring them (in controller) as `newPlayerName` and `newPlayerColor`

Note: in the future, it would help if you prepare a (functioning) jsfiddle for other to quickly and effectively concentrate on answering your questions. For example, with the script you posted, I have to mock up `$scope.getPlayerByColor` and `$scope.getPlayerByName` . Besides, you may want to refactor these two into services, and remember to initiate `$scope.players = []`